Compound Poisson Distribution/Mixture of Distributions
If for example a driver causes N accidents in a given year, and N has a Poisson Distribution with parameter λ. That λ parameter itself has a uniform distribution on an (0,1) interval. Is this a Compound Poisson Distribution or a mixture of distributions? The difference seems marginal, well to me at least
